# Is there a plugin like shadow for gradle 4.4 (fatJar)

Tags: gradle

I am trying to make a fatJar and then move it. The shadow plug fails on me saying it cannot find the plugin. I am trying to create a fatjar.

I have this which moves the file just fine but it includes EVERY single jar file, I just want one big one and then move it:

```
task copyJarIntoDockerDirectory(type: Copy) {

    dependsOn jar
    from configurations.runtime
    from jar
    into '../docker/ekomi-import'
    rename '(.*)-[0-9]+\\..*.jar', '$1.jar'
    doFirst { println 'before copy' }
    doLast { println 'after copy' }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.2` plugin with Gradle 3.0+. Your minimal `build.gradle` file could look like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.2"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"

task copyJarIntoDockerDirectory(type: Copy) {
  dependsOn shadowJar
  from 'build/libs/'
  into 'docker/ekomi-import'
}
```

In my case final JAR is called `products-service-all.jar`. When I run:

```
gradle clean copyJarIntoDockerDirectory && tree docker
```

I get following output in bash console:

```
products-service [master●●●] % gradle clean copyJarIntoDockerDirectory && tree docker

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
docker
└── ekomi-import
    └── products-service-all.jar

1 directory, 1 file
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have gradle 4.4 and it is giving me this error when I try your advice, ´Could not find method classpath() for arguments [io.ratpack:ratpack-gradle:1.5.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.´

Comment: @Drew1208 Sorry, that was obsolete, I was testing it in ratpack application. It shouldn't be in the exemplary code. Updated code sample. Please check now. I have tested it with Gradle 4.4.1

Comment: This might be the solution but it is failing now because this is a multi module project. Now the first module blows up with gradle clean build. I need to use the above solution in a few modules.

Comment: @Drew1208 please add this information to your question, it's crucial in this case. Maybe someone else faced similar issue and knows how to do it.

Comment: I was wrong it is creating it, I got it to work. However it it is just not moving it. It is creating two jar files too. One with a normal one and another with -all at the end.